# Should I run select * from server directly or make a stored procedure when populating a picker?

Tags: sql, node.js, oracle, plsql, backend

I have a predefined table with id and name. For example I have table with id and state name, so basically:

```
id  name
---------
1  Alabama
2  Alaska
3  Arizona
```

It is just use to populate a picker. My question is should I make basic "select * from sates" query on server or should I make a stored procedure for it? I was told to make all stored procedures and to not have any sql statements on server but I don't see a point in having procedure and it is actually very tedious thing to do.

Comment: A simple select hands down. Sotred procedures can be useful in some cases where you want to perform processing at the engine layer. They have drawbacks, however; it's tricky to debug them and also to version control their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will directly execute the query then (All plus points)

- You will have data in tabular form.
- You can use directly in any application.
- Need not to bother PL/SQL engine.
- No need of further data processing.

If you will wrap it in the procedure then (Procedure has its own advantage but not in your case)

- You will have to call it from another `PL/SQL block`. You can not use the procedure directly in the sql query. (Calling complexity)
- Procedure can not produce the table as an output, You will have to use the `sys_refcursor` to output the values. (Further data processing on result will be needed)
- If you just want to print the values from procedure then you will have to use dbms_output in the procedure with loop. (This is not useful in real application)

If you have a simple query then I can say, Use `view` to store the query in the database as follows:

```
create or replace your_view_name
as select id, name from your_table;
```

`Views` can be directly used in the query.

```
select * from your_view_name
```

Comment: So basically it is oke to use it this case and what is point of view if I don't have more complex query than this?

Comment: It is better to go with normal sql than procedure. and if you are told to make store query in the database then you can use the view. but don't use procedure for this sql query.